# ReactJS - Nested Array Prop Access is Returning Undefined

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am still relatively new to ReactJS and the best practices of traversing JSON with nested arrays and displaying the information as props or states. In my current setup, I am able to access my top-level JSON properties, the properties of a nested array `comments` and display them as states. However, I want to follow the ReactJS best practices of componentizing the individual elements that will display this JSON info by separating out the individual parts into props and also access another nested array that will only have one value. However, it doesn't appear that it finds my `comment.app_user[0].fullNameSlug` with the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'fullNameSlug' of undefined`.

Is this due to any of the reasons below?

1. Incorrect way to access nested array?
2. Not using a `key` within the prop component?

JSON:

```
{
        "recIdHash": "Zb2q97rX5n",
        "createdAtDateSlug": "9\/1\/2017 7:54 AM",
        "recCommentId": 9,
        "comment": "Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur porta, eros vitae laoreet pharetra, neque dolor facilisis augue, elementum maximus sapien tortor nec sem. Sed eget est sed felis tincidunt congue. Sed blandit neque vitae tellus interdum, non gravida tortor venenatis.",
        "userId": 237,
        "created_at": "2017-09-01T11:54:49.089Z",
        "updated_at": "2017-09-01T11:54:49.089Z",
        "user_id": 237,
        "app_user": {
          "userIdHash": "M3njEMRjba",
          "fullNameSlug": "Steve Matthews",
          "userId": 237,
          "firstName": "Steve",
          "lastName": "Matthews"
        }
      },
      {
        "recIdHash": "Zb2q97rX5n",
        "createdAtDateSlug": "9\/1\/2017 7:59 AM",
        "recCommentId": 10,
        "comment": "Sed laoreet felis ac interdum faucibus. Pellentesque non purus commodo, faucibus magna ac, pharetra urna. Sed sapien eros, efficitur in dui venenatis, euismod mattis nisl. Cras a posuere turpis. Morbi suscipit mollis risus, convallis auctor urna. Nam tristique, ex quis sodales tempor, massa urna maximus odio,",
        "userId": 240,
        "created_at": "2017-09-01T11:59:12.573Z",
        "updated_at": "2017-09-01T11:59:12.573Z",
        "user_id": 240,
        "app_user": {
          "userIdHash": "glk4YMY4eG",
          "fullNameSlug": "Ruth Wright",
          "userId": 240,
          "firstName": "Ruth",
          "lastName": "Wright"
        }
      }
}
```

React Components:

```
import React from 'react';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';


//Comments - Commentor
class Commentor extends React.Component{
    render(props){
        return (
            <div>
                <h4>{props.name}</h4>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

//Comments List
class Comments extends React.Component{

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = this.context.data || window.__INITIAL_STATE__ || {records: []};
    }

    fetchList() {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/test')
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            })  
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                let records = data.map((record, index) => {
                    return(
                        <div key={index}>
                        <li>{record.discovery}</li>
                        <ul>
                        {
                            record.record_comments.map((comment, i) => {
                                return (
                                        <div>
                                        <Commentor name={comment.app_user[0].fullNameSlug} />
                                        <li key={comment.recCommentId}>{comment.comment}</li>
                                        </div>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
                this.setState({ records: records });
            })  
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchList();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <h2>Comments List</h2>
            <ul>
            {this.state.records}
            </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

//Comment Container
export default class CommentBox extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="comment-form">
                <h1>Sweet it Worked</h1>
                <hr />
                <Comments />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: `app_user` doesn't have a 0 property. Just do `app_user.fullNameSlug`.

Comment: @AndrewLi thank you for pointing that out. I should have caught that immediately. However when I correct it to `<Commentor name={comment.app_user.fullNameSlug}` I have two new errors, one, that strangely says `name` is undefined, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` and two, `Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the top-level render call using <ul>.`. Any reason why the first error would appear despite this path being valid from the JSON I provided? Is the second looking for the use of `i` in my map?

Comment: I actually resolved the second error by moving the key to the div tag, but the first error still exists. Does it have something to do with my `<Commentor />` `prop` setup?